# Ubuntu LDAP Make Home Directory

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, mac-osx-server

I recently asked a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/58551/ubuntu-os-x-ldap-authentication) here about getting Ubuntu to authenticate via LDAP against an OS X server. The good news is, I got it to work and the clients are now authenticating, but my problem now is that pam_mkhomdir.so doesn't seem to be doing it's job. Here's my common-session file:

```
session sufficient pam_ldap.so
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
session required                        pam_permit.so
session required        pam_unix.so
session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/
session optional                        pam_ldap.so
session optional                        pam_ck_connector.so nox11
session optional pam_foreground.so
```

Because of this, every time an LDAP user tries to login, gdm tells them that their home directory is set to `/Network/[Servername]/User/[username]`. Based on this error, I'm guessing that pam_mkhomedir.so is being overridden by the LDAP provided home path, so my question is: is there a way to have the LDAP user's home directory created locally when they log in instead of it trying to use `/Volumes/[Servername]/...`?

Thanks in advance

**Update:** Kamil's response seems to have helped make some progress, but instead of gdm reporting the home directory as being set to `/Network/etc...`, it's saying it's set to `''` (null). I tried using

```
nss_map_attribute homeDirectory "/home/$username"
```

but this gave me the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The way we solved this is to add another attribute to LDAP, something like `linuxHomeDirectory` . Then you can create a mapping in `ldap.conf`:

```
nss_map_attribute homeDirectory linuxHomeDirectory
```

The for each user you set the attribute in LDAP to the path you want for their Linux home dir, such as `/home/$username` or whatnot.

If you have your home directories served from OS X server, you can mount those with an automounter in the `/Volumes/$servername/$path` hierarchy on Linux and then you don't need to do any LDAP attribute mangling.

**More info:**
Here's an article how to extend the LDAP schema in OpenDirectory: http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20060228230005854

To populate the user attributes you can use the `ldapadd` and `ldapmodify` tools.

Comment: When I tried using `nss_map_attribute homeDirectory linuxHomeDirectory`, I then got another error saying that the home directory was set to '', so I'm guessing that linuxHomeDirectory isn't being set. How could I go about setting this?

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to extend your LDAP scheme with a new attribute and then set the attribute for each user. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: How would I go about doing that, and by set the attribute for each user, do you mean go through and add something for each and every LDAP user? (That's around 700+ users in my case...)