# Using OSX home directories from linux

Tags: linux, mac-osx, mac-osx-server, home-directory

I'm running an OSX (Snow Leopard) Server with OpenDirectory, which is nothing else than a modified OpenLDAP with some Apple-specific schemas. However, I want to reuse this directory on some of my Linux (Debian Squeeze) boxes.

It's no problem to authenticate against OSXs LDAP Server, this works fine already. What I struggle with is the way the home folders are specified in OSX. If I query the passwd config on one of my linux machines, the OSX imported entries are looking like this

```
myaccount:x:1034:1026:Firstname Lastname:/Network/Servers/hostname.example.com/Volumes/MyShare/Users/myaccount:/bin/bash
```

While those network home folders might be fine for OSX-Clients, I don't want those server based paths on my linux machines. I saw that there is an **NFSHomeDirectory** Attribute in the OSX User inspector, but if I change this the whole user home path gets changed. Since my users should be able to login on both systems, OSX and Linux, this is not what I want.

Does anyone have an idea how I must configure OSX to make my linux machines use home folders like **/net/myaccount** and leave the configuration for OSX clients untouched?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/67803/ubuntu-ldap-make-home-directory looks promising. Either you'll have to add a new attribute for each user or use mount tricks.

Comment: ahh, did not find that one. Indeed it looks like this one could fit my needs.